# How to print function result in php?

Tags: javascript, function

I have this code and trying to print the results but it's not printing, please help. thankyou.

```js
function GetRandom() {
        var myElement = document.getElementById("pwbx")
 var myArray = ['item 1', 'item 2']; 
 var item = myArray[(Math.random()*myArray.length)|0];
        myElement.value = (item);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p> click the button to run the fumction</p>
        <button onclick="GetRandom()">Try it</button>
        <p id="pwbx"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

it works where i use the input form type to get the results but i don't want that, i want it to just be echoed as a normal text in the page. thanks. i am a noob in this stuff so looking for help.

```js
   

 function GetRandom() {
            var myElement = document.getElementById("pwbx")
         var myArray = ['item 1', 'item 2']; 
         var item = myArray[(Math.random()*myArray.length)|0];
            myElement.value = (item);
 }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Click the button to display a random number between 1 and 10.</p>
        <button onclick="GetRandom()">Try it</button>
        <input name="test" type="text" id="pwbx" value="">
        <p id="pwbx"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: where do you want to print? Is it the screen or the printer?

Comment: print in the page like: result=item1

Comment: My plain-old-javascript is a bit rusty, but `myElement.value = (item);` is trying to set the value of a p tag (which doesn't exist).  Wouldn't you use something like innerHtml?

Comment: assuming `getRandom` is a js function inside a `<script>` tag. You will actually want to set `window.getRandom = function(){...}`

Comment: (a) That looks like JavaScript. not PHP. (b) Your goal is unclear. Please read [ask] and try again.

Comment: The `<p>` tag doesn't have a `.value` property.  You'll have to use something like `.innerHTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<p>` tag doesn't have a `value` property.  Use `innerHTML` instead.

```js
function GetRandom()
    {
        var myElement = document.getElementById("pwbx")
  var myArray = ['item 1', 'item 2']; 
  var item = myArray[(Math.random()*myArray.length)|0];
        myElement.innerHTML = item;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display a random number between 1 and 10.</p>

<button onclick="GetRandom()">Try it</button>


<p id="pwbx"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hello, instead of using <p id="pwbx"></p> is their a way to use php echo method. thanks

Comment: You're not even using PHP here.  PHP happens on the server.  This is in your web browser.  You may have used PHP to get it to the browser, but PHP is long finished.  It's apples and oranges.  If you need to get some info off of the server, you'll need to look into AJAX, at which point you'd be well served to look into JQuery.  But first you need to get your head around the difference between JS and PHP.  Short version: No, it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

as Tim said in the comments... you will want to use `innerHTML` not `value` for non input tags....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>
        <p> click the button to run the fumction</p>
        <button onclick="GetRandom()">Try it</button>
        <p id="pwbx"></p>
    </body>

    <script>
        var myArray = ['item 1', 'item 2']; //should move this outside of getRandom so it doesn't reallocate each run;

        function GetRandom() {    
            var randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(myArray.length));    
            var item = myArray[randomInt];

            document.getElementById("pwbx").innerHTML = item;
        }
    </script>
</html>
```